# How can I cache data in react native expo?

Tags: react-native, caching, expo

I would like to store my data in some cache in react native expo.

Which technic (packages) should I use?

i would like to store some json data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

[AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage)

[MMKV Storage](https://github.com/ammarahm-ed/react-native-mmkv-storage)

If you need a complete database solution you can try [WatermelonDB](https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB)

I strongly suggest the MMKV Storage, it is blazingly fast compared to AsyncStorage. This completely depends on your use-cases and usages. So pick carefully :) However, if you need a basic cache, you cannot go wrong with AsyncStorage, it is very basic.

I suggest you that read some documentation for caching solutions first :)